# How do I check the message size from recvfrom()?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, sockets

How do I check that the message from [recvfrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the correct size in C or C++ on windows?

Thank you.

Comment: What's Visual Studio 3.0?  And what does .NET have to do with this?  Do you mean the Visual C++ compiler that came with "Visual Studio .NET 2003"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recvfrom` returns the number of bytes in the datagram actually received.

All you need is

```
if (iResult < 0) { /* network error */ }
if (iResult != BufLen) { /* wrong size */ }
```

---

Old answer, off topic

You should declare a variable to hold the size, and pass its address as the `fromlen` parameter.

`recvfrom` will fill in the actual size of the <strike>datagram</strike> sender's address (IP and port, so you can send a reply if you want).

Then you can test the actual size against what you expected.

Comment: @Tommy: Really sorry about that, the `fromlen` parameter gets the size of the sender's address (IP and port), not the packet size.  The size of the packet content is the return value.  Fixed my answer.